# Basic Java Stripes Example Hello World

Tags: java, jsp, web, frameworks, stripes

So I am trying to use the Stripes framework for Java to run a hello world application. Using the example on wikipedia here: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stripes_%28framework%29#Example

So with the jsp file and the java file in my tomcat server I try to run the jsp file and it only come up with:

Hello

Try again

Which is what is in the jsp file but it does not seem to use the java file.

Are there other things I am supposed to have or am I trying to access it the wrong way?

Comment: How are you accessing it? Like, what are you passing in for the name?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but I do know that your setter,

```
public void setContext(ActionBeanContext context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

should be **before** your getter,

```
public ActionBeanContext getContext() {
    return context;
}
```

not after.

Comment: why must the setter come first?

Answer (score 1):

Having a look at the official webpage for Stripes UrlBinding

http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/javadoc/net/sourceforge/stripes/action/UrlBinding.html

I can see that the code should work fine but as Dave asks, what Url are you calling?

```
http://localhost:8080/hello-/Paul.html
```

should work, but you could also simply the UrlBinding - as per the supplied link.